# Does it affect the jest testing performance if shallow rendering done in beforeEach

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

If shallow rendering is done in beforeEach will it take more time and affect the performance of unit test cases.

Shall I do beforeEach or beforeAll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what your intentions are. If your test cases mutate the state of the rendered component and you want each test to start off from a freshly rendered component, then use beforeEach to ensure correctness of each test. If tests don't mutate the component's state or it doesn't matter, use beforeAll to avoid unnecessary renders.

If you have only a few tests where you want to begin from a fresh render, you can rerender the component in those few tests to override the render in the beforeAll.

And for the performance question, I think beforeEach definitely makes things slower than beforeAll but I don't think that is a difference you will ever notice unless you are running your tests on a decades old processor.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @jacksonk.dev for the insights. I have idea about `beforeEach` vs `beforeAll`. I was just concerned about performance issue.